# How to update a property of a sub-document in an embedded array?

Tags: mongodb

Given the following document in the database, I want to update pincode of address array.

I'm using the $ positional locator in Mongodb. But this does not find the document embedded multiple levels.

```
"_id": ObjectId("58b91ccf3dc9021191b256ff"),
"phone": 9899565656,
"Email": "sumit@mail.com",
"Organization": "xyz",
"Name": "sumit",
"address": [{
    "city": "chennai",
    "pincode": 91,
    "_id": ObjectId("58b91db48682ab11ede79b28"),
    "choice": [{
        "_id": ObjectId("58b91fa6901a74124fd70d89")
    }]
}]
```

Using this query to update.

```
db.presenters.update({"Email":"sumit@mail.com","address.city":"chennai"},{$set:{"address.$.pincode.": 95 }})
```

Comment: There is a nextra '.' after '$.pincode' which is not needed. Please try it like this: {"address.$.pincode": 95 }

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have incorrect field name while updating, an extra dot at the end. Try following

```
db.presenters.update({"Email":"sumit@mail.com","address.city":"chennai"},
   {$set:{"address.$.pincode": 95 }})
```